# Unity: Make object appear or disappear randomly during game play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 3D, 1st person maze game in Unity. The objective of the game is to reach the other side of the maze before time is up. To make the game fun, for every round a player starts the maze map randomly generates walls so every maze is unique so the player can't memorize a path. I've decided what I should do is create a grid of walls like this...

(Imagine that the lines are the walls, each segment is an individual wall object)

[image]

When a player starts, each wall segment will have a chance of disappearing, so imagine that this grid will transform into something like this...

[image]

How do I do that? I will be using C#. Basically, I want to wall to turn invisible and be passable if it is selected to "disappear". The algorithm will be

```
game starts
probability that wall will disappear = 1/3;
wall disappears = true;
if(true){
    wall becomes invisible and passable
}
 else{
    wall stays there
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to make an Object disappear in Unity.

The wall to make disappear:

```
public GameObject wallObject;
```

**1**.Deactive it

```
wallObject.SetActive(false);
```

**2**.Disable the Renderer component of the Wall then the collider so that other GameObjects can pass through it

```
wallObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
wallObject.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
```

**3**.Destroy it.

```
Destroy(wallObject);
```

You can use [`Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) to generate the number number then use one of the method above to hide that wall.

Comment: Thanks, but ran into a problem, somehow it either destroys or keep ALL the walls, I want it to affect the wall individually